# Find the limit of this product series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$U_0 = 1$

$U_{n+1} = U_n \cdot \left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}\right)\right)$

So $U_1 = \frac{9}{10}$

$U_2 = \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{99}{100}$

$U_3 = \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{999}{1000}$

What's the limit of this series?

We can easily show that $0 < U_n \le 1$, and with a simple program we see that it converges to ~0.89.

I have tried to use mainly induction to prove a number of things but I can't find the right proposition to prove.

One of the thing I tried was to prove that this series was always greater than the series $V_{n+1}=V_n + 0.08^n$ with $V_1=.8$ but no luck, and I actually thing it's false.

Thanks to @heropup I realized that I am asking about the convergence of Euler's function for q = 0.1: $\phi(0.1)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function

Comment: It is a sequence!

Comment: No it can't be greater than .9

Comment: $0.8900100999...$

Comment: Yes +David that's about right, now how do you find the exact limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Mathematica* evaluates this product as a $q$-Pochhammer symbol; i.e., $$(a;q)_\infty = \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1 - a q^k),$$ for $a = q = 1/10$.  I do not believe there is an elementary closed form for such a choice.  It is, however, easy to show that $(q;q)_\infty$ is convergent for all $q \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Your answer just lead me to Euler Function, I seem to be asking about the convergence of $\phi(0.1)$

Comment: $0.8900100999989990000001000099999999899999000000000010000009999999999998999999900000000000000100000000999999999999999989999999990000000000000000001000000000099999999999999999999899999999999000000000000000000000010000000000009999999999999999999999998999999999999900000000000000000000000000100000000000000999999999999999999999999999989999999999999990000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000099999999999999999999999999999999899999999999999999000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000009999999999999999999999999999999999998999999999999999999900000000000000000000000000000$

Comment: May I ask what is "Mathematica"? Is it Wolfram Mathematica?